# How to access to the WebViewPage instance from created IView in RazorViewEngine?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my web MVC application i define a custom `RazorViewEngine` like below:

```
    public class MyRazorEngine : RazorViewEngine
    {
        protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath)
        {
            var tmp = base.CreateView(controllerContext, viewPath, masterPath);

            // *** here some action i want do by (tmp as MyWebPageBase).
            // *** for example access to the 'SomeField' value which assigned into (tmp as MyWebPageBase).

            return tmp;

        }
   }
```

and i define my Views inheriting MyWebViewPage.cs:

```
public abstract class MyWebViewPage<TModel> : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    public int SomeField{ get; set;};
}
```

Now , my problem is that i cant access to the rendered view specially `MyWebPageBase` from `RazorViewEngine` class. how do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do as to where you would do it.

```
base.CreateView(controllerContext, viewPath, masterPath)
```

returns an `IView` and `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage` does not implement `IView` so you cannot convert between them plus this would too late in the pipeline anyway.

You could subclass RazorView and override RenderView method becuase as you can see below it's handed an WebViewPage in it's instance parameter but this again might be too late for whatever you're trying to do:

```
  protected override void RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, object instance)
        {
            if (writer == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("writer");
            }

            WebViewPage webViewPage = instance as WebViewPage;
            if (webViewPage == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    String.Format(
                        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                        MvcResources.CshtmlView_WrongViewBase,
                        ViewPath));
            }
```

Or you could implement your own `IViewPageActivator` and plug that into the Resolver:

```
public interface IViewPageActivator {
    object Create(ControllerContext controllerContext, Type type);
}
```

[Brad Wilson introduces that here : View Page Activator](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt11-view-page-activator.html)

Comment: But i did not find RenderView in WebViewPage class to override it.

Comment: @AliAdl RenderView is a member of RazorView. So you subclass RazorView and within that override RenderView for access.

Comment: ok i subclass the RazorView named MyRazorView, but i cant cast the created view instance to MyRazorView type in MyRazorEngine.CreateView method. it throws Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Mvc.RazorView' to type 'Admin.App_Start.MyRazorView' exception!

Comment: You've sublcassed the RazorViewEngine, MyRazorEngine : RazorViewEngine and you're overriding CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath), so did you create a new MyRazorView in the override or are you still calling base.CreateView(controllerContext, viewPath, masterPath)? The base method is only returning a RazorView.... that's why you're overriding it right?